# Which serial protocol or encoding scheme does this scoreboard use?

Tags: digital-logic, serial, signal, communication, protocol

I am trying to decode a signal stream coming from a Nevco scoreboard controller:

[image]

Packets like this are sent every ~2.7 ms.

I suspect it is some sort of UART signal because it is on the RX line of a ATMEGA48, but I cannot identify the finer protocol details like parity and stop bits. All the combinations I have tried returns junk data, so it may be another encoding scheme.

What's unusual is that the same signal is also sent to the MOSI pin of the microcontroller, but there is no clock signal anywhere.

A .vcd file is [here](http://pastebin.com/nSFC7U7W).

The shortest pulses (both high and low) are always 8us in length.

[image: Imgur]
This is what two packets look like. Anyone got ideas?

Comment: Have you measured out all the pulse widths, both positive and negative?

Comment: Yes. There isn't a pattern that I can identify, but the first packet goes like this in microseconds: 8, 72, 8, 33, 16, 8, 24, 8, 24, 29, 8, 64, 8, 29, 8 40, 8, 40... and so on. I've pastebinned a [VCD file](http://pastebin.com/nSFC7U7W) for reference.

Comment: Have you looked at the signal with a scope? It may be partially analog, or more complex then it looks.

Comment: It's vaguely reminicient of Manchester encoding but the long pieces don't look right... I'm guessing - reverse engineering protocols is really hard work.

Comment: @xyk2, what's a good Windows app to view the VCD file in? Just tried one called PulseView but it didn't seem to like it.

Comment: ... Nevco made their own protocol ... I made the reverse engineering and it work well ;-)

Comment: @Dr.SK -- make that an answer and I'll upvote it :)